# Windows Server 2012 R2 lost ability to browse the Internet after RRAS setup

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2, rras

I have a Windows 2012 R2 server that is set up to be our VPN server. Company workers use this server to connect and gain access to the company's network. This part is working fine, no issues here.

The problem is that after the RRAS role setup the server itself can't browse the Internet any longer.

The server has 2 network connections, one set up with our internal network settings and the other is set with a public Internet IP address. That NIC is the input for the VPN.

I already tried everything I found searching the net but no success so far. I can ping any site on the command prompt but when on IE I can't access anything.

I already disabled IE Enhanced Security Configuration and also tested with the firewall completely off.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check the IP-Filters on the NIC. The RRAS Wizard applys very strict IP filter rules on your inbound interface by default (if you don't chose otherwise). This can be don in RRAS MMC -> Interfaces.

On the other hand, it's not wise (in *most* cases) to have your RRAS gateway surfing around the internet.

Comment: 1st thank you for your answer. Yes those filters are very strict and I was missing filters for TCP ports 80 and 443. Problem solved.